# Virtual Key codes defining

Tags: c, virtual-keyboard

Hello I have checked  [Virtual Key Codes MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx)  in C and it shows character `A` as  `0x41` , I wanted to know how I'd be able to get the difference between a lower case and an upper case letter in C? is there an attribute for it

I have checked and it returns the same VK code for both upper and lower case letters.

Comment: @Internal Server Error I am trying to print the Virtual Key Codes of the letters that I write, I am using `HOOK` procedure for it. But when I get the vk codes they're the same for both upper and lower case letters? i want to be able identify if it's lower or not, how do I achieve it ?

Comment: there is no notion of lowercase vs upper case for key codes, because they correspond to the keys on your keyboard. The difference would be you checking for the key code `VK_LSHIFT` or `VK_RSHIFT` being pressed while the letter key code is pressed

Comment: maybe in conjunction with shift, 0x10?

Comment: Virtual key codes in *what* context? The linked page say "A key" the point being the physical *key* pressed. They don't also chart "a key".

Comment: @Austin_Anderson thanks, that's what I should do, definitely!

Comment: @yano thanks that's true

Comment: Remember that you can also have combinations of VK_CONTROL and VK_ALT in addition to VK_SHIFT.